# Google App Engine runs no instances after a successful deployment

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have been using Google Cloud Platform for 3 months.
It is cool, but sometimes it makes me mad.

Recently I have struggled against Google App Engine's "no instances" problem like this:

1. When many GAE instances are running well
2. A new deployment is done (with appcfg.py)
3. All GAE instances are gone, and no instances are running
   ("This app has no instances deployed." Google Developers Console says.)

Today I have experienced that problem more than 3 times.
When the problem had occurred, I tried something like these:

- re-deployment (same version)
- re-deployment (another version)
- change default version

The problem is resolved after some time(10~20 minutes).
But I don't know whether the problem is resolved because of my tries or not.

I have encountered the problem rarely, but recently the problem happens  frequently.  (And it is very annoying.)

--

I am using python27 runtime and automatic_scaling like this:

```
# app.yaml
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

#...

builtins:
- deferred: on

inbound_services:
- warmup

instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_pending_latency: 30ms
  min_idle_instances: 2
  max_idle_instances: 10
```

Comment: I am also seeing this

Comment: What are you getting when trying to hit the app right after deploying? sounds like no instances are running because no traffic has been recieved.

Answer (score 3):

I gone through the Google groups and found that many of the application facing the same issue on that specific date. It seems that during that period there was some problem, which is now get fixed.The links for Google Groups [1][2].

[1] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/z7mn5ay11gc

[2] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/whriQ28tPMg

Comment: Yes, the problem doesn't happen now.  I was frustrated because I don't know what's going on GAE that time. Thank you for the links.